# C# winform TCP/IP problem sending string to stream

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient

I am trying to convert an existing C# console app code to a C# winform the code below works well.

```
class Program
    {
        const int PORT_NO = 49211;
        const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //---data to send to the server---
            string textToSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text---
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

But when i tried to convert this into a winform app, the application freeze until i manually stop in on Visual Studio. I Attached it into a button click event.

```
const int PORT_NO = 49211;
const string SERVER_IP = "127.0.0.1";
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //---data to send to the server---
    string textToSend = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, PORT_NO);
    NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

    //---send the text---
    lstProgress.Items.Add("Sending : " + textToSend);
    nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

    //---read back the text---
    byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
    int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
    lstProgress.Items.Add("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead));
    client.Close();
}
```

Any suggestion would be great thanks in advance!

Comment: You're running your code in the UI thread. The UI is blocking on your code.

Comment: debug it. On which line does it freeze?

Comment: @vasily.sib so the `int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);` is causing the problem going to look at the steam.Read documentation.